# Read Page wise PDF through pdfminer in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdfminer

I am reading the attached PDF through pdfminer but not able to read it page wise.

```
for a in range(0, no_of_pages-1):
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos=[a], maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        text = retstr.getvalue()
        print "txt", text
        extract_pdf_data(text, a+1, path)
        retstr.flush()
```

For 1st page it works fine but for 2nd page it returns the result for both 1st and 2nd page and also page 6 is not being read right. 1st column text appear in 3rd column.

Please help me in reading the page wise content and also pdf content will not shuffle between content.

Comment: PDF link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WDScThzf3W-ao-smrEcDLp6PNGjl2HJH/view?usp=sharing

python code - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0o5rnVAjgWA3e7Z4LAvvHL36RcIpaeF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can anyone answer on this... I am stuck in my work.